# How to cache all site pages with Redis in Django?

Tags: django, redis, django-redis

Is it possible to cache all site pages automatically with `Redis` in `Django`? I'm using `django-redis` package. How could I implement a function to scan all urls and cache each one?

Comment: What's the reason you want to cache all pages? I suppose you're pages are dynamically generated and may contain different context at different times for different users. Maybe you'd rather like to cache the query results from the database?

Comment: The site is like a journal or a blog. The old "posts" are almost static, rarely changed, but there is always new "posts".

Comment: Do you know [django-cacheops](https://github.com/Suor/django-cacheops)? If not, then please take a look. I think it could be something for your issue.